# STD. AMERICAN - 2 over 1, Bidding with a 5 card major and 16 points

Tags: bridge

A question on which i think the Jury is still out - With a 5 card Major and 16 points - lets say 5-3-3-2 do I open 1 NT or bid 1 of the major.  And how do I show my partner a medium hand if I do open 1 Spade.  With a 5-4-2-2 I could bid 2 hearts as my 2nd bid but with a 4-5-2-2 I couldn't even do that as I would be reversing - which normally shows 17-18.

And if I bid 1NT then do I need to be playing Puppet Stayman?

Many thanks for your time and patience.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of partnership agreement. In particular, it is reasonable either to *almost always* or *almost never* open `1NT` with a 5-card major.

If you are in the *almost always* camp, assuming a 15-17 NT opener, you should open any 5332 hand with a 5-card major and 15-16 HCP `1NT` unless all of your points are in your major and one of the side suits. These bidders will also likely open `1NT` with the appropriate point count and semibalanced shapes that are difficult to rebid (e.g. `2=4=5=2`, `2=4=2=5`, but *not* `4=2=5=2` since you can raise or introduce spades without reversing). Puppet Stayman is not a necessity, but it is useful. Justin Lall has a [useful post about Puppet Stayman](http://csbnews.org/puppet-stayman-after-a-1n-opener-by-justin-lall/?lang=en).

If you are in the *almost never* camp, you should open those hands one of the major. The types of hands that would open `1NT` with a 5-card major would be those that have positional stoppers or half-stoppers in 2 or 3 of the side suits (like `QTx`, `Kx`, `Qx`) along with a poor 5-card major.

The most important thing is to be on the same page as your partner.

As to how to rebid after opening 1 of a major with a semibalanced or balanced 15-17, here's a guide:

- If you have a 4-card suit lower than the suit you opened, rebid that.
- If your shape is `4=5=2=2`, rebid 2C.
- Otherwise, rebid your longer minor at the two-level, preferring to bid a 3-card club suit before a 3-card diamond suit. However, be sure to discuss this with your partner -- you may find that you both prefer to rebid 2D with something like `xx AKJxx AKx xxx`.

Obviously, if partner invites, you'll accept. If partner takes a simple preference to your first major, you will probably want to make a game try:

- If you have 3-card support for partner's suit, bid it as cheaply as possible.
- If you have a truly excellent 5-card major (AKJTx or better) and values that look better for a suit contract than NT (fitting honors for partner's suit, side suits with either no honors or with quick tricks), you might make a try by rebidding 3 of your major.
- Otherwise, `2NT`.

Comment: If you really don't like rebidding 2C on 4-5-2-2 hands, you can either play Flannery or play this reverse a little light (possibly even a nonforcing 15-18, with stronger hands requiring a different bid).

Comment: One paragraph to describe the *almost always* approach; Five paragraphs to describe the *almost never* approach. Guess my preference. I add the constraint of never opening 1NT with a weak doubleton in the other major, in case partner transfers into it.

Comment: Hi Ruds, I am keen to bid 1NT to show my partner my point range so If I open 1NT with a 5-3-4-2, how do I show my partner I have a 5 carder without Puppet stayman.  If my partner bids 1C and I bid 1S how do I show 5 and not 4. If partner bids 2NT then I could either pass if I have 15 points or bid 3S showing a 5 carder? What if I have a 4-5-2-2, then what could be my bid ? what if my partner transfers me to a Minor? Thanks...

Comment: With 5332 you can't show a 5-card suit without puppet (except over the 2nt invitation when you're strong enough to accept), but I find this disadvantage is outweighed by letting your partner know your strength and approximate shape early in the auction. With 4=5=2=2 exactly I would not open 1NT. With a 5-card minor and a 4-card major and 15-16 high card points, 1NT is OK and solves a lot of rebid problems.

Comment: @nick You have a lot of questions, which probably belong in questions not comments :)  1C-1S with 5 is the reason for New Minor Forcing and XYZ conventions, which allow you to bid the other minor (2d) in a sequence like, say, 1c-1s-1nt-2d, asking your partner if s/he has 4h or 3s.